# Hooking up a variable frequency drive

Tags: motor, mains, three-phase, single-phase

I have a 3-phase blower motor that I am looking to control from a Danfoss VLT 2800 that I purchased on eBay.

I have in the shop a receptacle that looks like this: [image: receptacle image]

If I put a meter from neutral (horizontal middle) to either hot side (the verticals) I get 120v.  Across the hots I get 240v.  The table suggests that for single phase I should only be connecting two wires, including a neutral.  But with the neutral I have I only get the 120v.  Should I just be connecting the two hots?

For reference, our building has high-leg delta service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

European phase voltage is 230 Vrms (line voltage is therefore 400 Vrms).  Here in the US we have to connect the two "hots" to get a comparable voltage, that is 240 Vrms.

You are fine connecting one split-phase "hot" to L1 and the other one to L2.  Make sure to connect the ground as well.  The split-phase neutral should be left disconnected.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, two hots. And most important is the ground, leave the neutral unconnected. By the way what's "high-leg delta service", and the table you are refering at is not visible. Also you have to check the motor connection star/delta for correct voltage.

Comment: Right click the link and select open in a new tab worked for me to see the image. It is essentially the same as the one provided by SunnyBoyNY.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-leg_delta